# How to dynamically update picturebox picture using pictures from resources without using "My" statement

Tags: c#, dynamic, picturebox, windows-forms-designer

I'd like to run a code with database of strings containing the location of the images but I will use arrays over here as an example:

```
string [] images = {Resource\picture1,Resource\picture2};
```

But when I try to run it with this code:

```
this.pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @""+images[0];
```

it does not work 
I also tried using:

```
this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@""+images[0]);
```

and it does not work

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: The line: string [] images = {Resource\picture1,Resource\picture2}; is not compiling. Do you mean: string [] images = {@"Resource\picture1,Resource\picture2"}; ?

Comment: sorry it suppose to be like string [] images{"Resource\image1","Resource\image2"}

Comment: So do you mean: string [] images = {@"Resource\picture1",@"Resource\picture2"}; Is that already the solution?

Comment: 'Doesn't work' is not a sufficient problem statement! Is there an error message and if so what is is it precisely? also: What do you mean by '_'My' statement_' ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
try
{
    string[] images = { @"Resource\picture1", @"Resource\picture2" };
    this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(images[0]);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

If the file does not exist, you will get an exception, that you can catch and handle or before loading try it it exists expicitly.